# How to drag images from a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

check this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/6WpKf/)

We can drag and drop the "Drag me downX" lines in to the canvas div; the line of text will stay there while there will be a translucent line of text following the mouse. I want to have this same effect dragging the line of text *out* of the canvas. Yet, once the text is dropped in the canvas it cannot be moved. How can I go about achieving the above (it having the same effects as described above is very important)?

**HTML**

```
  <ul id="drag">
     <li class="new-item">Drag me down1</li>
     <li class="new-item">Drag me down2</li>
     <li class="new-item">Drag me down3</li>
  </ul>    

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
 $("li").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
 });
 $("#myCanvas").droppable({
    accept: "li",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
       var context = $(this)[0].getContext("2d");
       context.font = "16px helvetica";
       context.fillText($(ui.draggable).clone().text(), ui.position.left - event.target.offsetLeft, ui.position.top - event.target.offsetTop);
    }
 });
```

**CSS**

```
 li{
    font-family:helvetica;
    list-style-type:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might have been an issue because its basically an element being dragged and dropped on itself. I created a hidden canvas and superimposed the original canvas over the new one. When the drag event is fired the hidden canvas is placed on a higher z-index and gets the coordinate information to pass to the original canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Once you drop the element onto the `<canvas>` it loses all meaning as the text gets rasterized.  As such, there is no way to get the text out.  The best that you could do is append invisible copies of the dragged tag to the canvas and then whenever there is any drag event out of the canvas, pop an element and drag it where you want.  However, this will not get you the exact tag that you want necessarily.

If you are really looking for a challenge, you can take a look at this question which is about selecting text in a canvas after it's been rasterized. [How to Make Canvas Text Selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451635/how-to-make-canvas-text-selectable)

Comment: I see. I don't really care about the meaning of the text; I'd really like to do this with an image. drag the image in; and then be able to drag the image out; yet I guess the image loses all meaning as well? Is there no way to set it to "draggable" to be able to accomplish what I described above?

Comment: As long as you're using a `<canvas>`, anything that goes in and gets rasterized will be lost contextually.  Is there a specific reason to use a `<canvas>`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to accomplish something like this: casetagram.com/builder If you choose "photo" in the menu at the right, you can upload photos and you will see them applied to the canvas using the gloabCompositeOperation = 'source-atop', etc. You can also drag the photo from the canvas the way I described as well; I am trying to figure out how to accomplish that